# Using JQuery .insertBefore() Method isn't Executing in the Order Given

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem where the matching end tag is migrating up to it's pair, instead of wrapping content as in the order I have listed the statements. I am missing how/why this would happen. 
The JS Function:

```
$('.add-contributor-button').click(function(){
 $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"contributor\">").insertBefore('.add-contributor-button');
 $("<select>").insertBefore('.add-contributor-button');
  $("<option value=\"\" name=\"author\">Author</option>").insertBefore('.add-contributor-button');
  $("<option value=\"\" name=\"editor\">Editor</option>").insertBefore('.add-contributor-button');
  $("<option value=\"\" name=\"illustrator\">Illustrator</option>").insertBefore('.add-contributor-button');
  $("<option value=\"\" name=\"translator\">Translator</option>").insertBefore('.add-contributor-button');
  $("<option value=\"\" name=\"other\">Other</option>").insertBefore('.add-contributor-button');
$("</select>").insertBefore('.add-contributor-button');
});
```

The HTML before(and what is the target for duplication.):

```
<input type="text" name="contributor">
<select>
 <option value="" name="author">Author</option>
 <option value="" name="editor">Editor</option>
 <option value="" name="illustrator">Illustrator</option>
 <option value="" name="translator">Translator</option>
 <option value="" name="other">Other</option>
</select>
<div class="add-contributor-button">+ Add Contributor</div>
```

The Resulting HTML once the div is clicked(I am getting this from Firefox 50.1.0 inspector tool):

```
<input type="text" name="contributor">
<select>
 <option value="" name="author">Author</option>
 <option value="" name="illustrator">Illustrator</option>
 <option value="" name="translator">Translator</option>
 <option value="" name="other">Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="contributor">
<select></select>
 <option value="" name="author">Author</option>
 <option value="" name="illustrator">Illustrator</option>
 <option value="" name="translator">Translator</option>
 <option value="" name="other">Other</option>
<div class="add-contributor-button">+ Add Contributor</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue here is a misunderstanding of how `insertBefore()` works in jQuery.

`insertBefore()` is not used to build lines of HTML. If you specify an HTML element like `$("<select>").insertBefore()`, it will create a new `<select>` element and add it to your page, closing tags and all.

That being said, we can keep that code. We *do* want a new `<select>` element, after all. But rather than *inserting* all our options, we want to **append** them, which adds them as children to the targeted element.

Like so:

```
$('.add-contributor-button').click(function() {
    $("<input type=\"text\" name=\"contributor\">").insertBefore('.add-contributor-button');
    $("<select>").insertBefore('.add-contributor-button')
        .append("<option value=\"\" name=\"author\">Author</option>")
        .append("<option value=\"\" name=\"editor\">Editor</option>")
        .append("<option value=\"\" name=\"illustrator\">Illustrator</option>")
        .append("<option value=\"\" name=\"translator\">Translator</option>")
        .append("<option value=\"\" name=\"other\">Other</option>");
});
```

---

I should really note, there are some more efficient ways of doing this. I was in the process of typing one, but [zer00ne has posted a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41752422/2026606) of how you can take the *original* inputs, and use the button to simply *duplicate* them instead of creating new ones from scratch each time.

Comment: This 100% worked, thank you for the clarification on what I was doing.

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself some headache and wrap `<input>` and `<select>` in a container (I used a `<fieldset>`) and then `.clone()` it.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('.add-contributor-button').click(function() {
  var clone = $('.original').clone(true, true);
  clone.removeClass('original').addClass('clone').insertBefore('.add-contributor-button');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset class='original set'>
  <input type="text" name="contributor">
  <select>
    <option value="" name="author">Author</option>
    <option value="" name="editor">Editor</option>
    <option value="" name="illustrator">Illustrator</option>
    <option value="" name="translator">Translator</option>
    <option value="" name="other">Other</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>

<div class="add-contributor-button">+ Add Contributor</div>
```

Comment: Was in the process of typing something like this into my answer, but I like your method better anyways. I'll include a reference to yours instead. +1

Comment: I upvoted you for your fortitude in analyzing that mess.